# Apache 2.4 .htaccess friendly URL rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Having some issues understanding the .htaccess file and getting it to work properly.  .htaccess is recognized....i entered plain test at the top and got the internal server error.  And it appears mod-rewrite is working...because I downloaded a test php file and it works.

I am using Apache 2.4.23 with no php pages

However i cant seem to get this to work right.

I am trying to take this url

```
http://example.com/ProjectTest/index.shtml?dynContent=Content1
```

and rewrite it like this

```
http://example.com/ProjectTest/Content1
```

I am also trying to do this generically across the site since ?dynContent=whatever will be a constant.....and trying to keep the same path.....like the below example

Change this

```
http://example.com/ProjectTest/ProjectFolder/index.shtml?dynContent=Content1
```

to this

```
http://example.com/ProjectTest/ProjectFolder/Content1
```

I am not very good with the .htaccess files

**UPDATE:** Ok...I got this to work.....not really sure why it works....but when I type in the test-dev/ProjectTest/apples or test-dev/ProjectTest/oranges it calls up the appropriate content.

This is what I used

```
RewriteRule ^ProjectTest/([^/\.]+)/?$ ProjectTest/index.shtml?dynContent=$1 [L]
```

and then I rewrote it to be this and now it works for any directory

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/index.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dynContent=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/(.+)+/index.shtml $1/%1 [PT]
```

This requires `mod_rewrite` to be activated. The value of the bracket in `dynContent=(.+)` is stored in `%1` and the bracket's value in `^/(.+)+/index.shtml` is stored in `$1`. Both together creates your target path `http://example.com/ProjectTest/ProjectFolder/Content1`

Comment: I corrected the index.shtml misspelling and tried it and it didn't work for me....I also create a phpinfo page and checked the modules that were loaded and mod_rewrite was loaded...below is the info from the phpinfo page.

Comment: Server Root D:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23
Loaded Modules core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cache mod_cache_disk mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env mod_file_cache mod_headers mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_userdir mod_vhost_alias mod_php5

Comment: What exactly did go wrong? error message? log entries? something to work with? Because the rule itself should be correct :/

Comment: Yes..it looks like it should work.....been doing some reading on differences between Apache 2.2 and 2.4 mod_rewrite.  Saw something last night where is was suggested to use mod_rewrite in the virtual host directory.  Newbie to writing .htaccess....will have to find and look at the logs if any....or what I have to do to turn turn that on.  Will try that after work today.

Comment: Let me know if you have any specific questions, we are running on both, Apache 2.2 and 2.4. If you have full access to your server you won't need and shouldn't use .htaccess, because it only increases complexity if you don't really need it. Stick to the standard config files. To turn on rewrite log: Search for `LogLevel` in your config, which probably is set to `error` and add the rewrite:trace in that line like this: `LogLevel error rewrite:trace2`. Then restart and test again, rewrites will appear in error.log (search with `tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:' `) Trace2 should be enough.

Comment: Ok...this is what I see
[Thu Apr 06 18:23:26.019140 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16684:tid 1188] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62514] 127.0.0.1 - - [test-dev/sid#1f4e7367798][rid#1f4e94b54f0/initial] [perdir D:/wamp64/www/test-dev/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp64/www/test-dev/ProjectTest/index.shtml -> ProjectTest/index.shtml

Comment: [Thu Apr 06 18:23:26.019642 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16684:tid 1188] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62514] 127.0.0.1 - - [test-dev/sid#1f4e7367798][rid#1f4e94b54f0/initial] [perdir D:/wamp64/www/test-dev/] applying pattern '^/(.*)/index.shtml' to uri 'ProjectTest/index.shtml'
[Thu Apr 06 18:23:26.019642 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16684:tid 1188] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62514] 127.0.0.1 - - [test-dev/sid#1f4e7367798][rid#1f4e94b54f0/initial] [perdir D:/wamp64/www/test-dev/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp64/www/test-dev/ProjectTest/index.shtml -> ProjectTest/index.shtml

Comment: [Thu Apr 06 18:23:26.019642 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16684:tid 1188] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62514] 127.0.0.1 - - [test-dev/sid#1f4e7367798][rid#1f4e94b54f0/initial] [perdir D:/wamp64/www/test-dev/] applying pattern '^/(.*)/index.shtml' to uri 'ProjectTest/index.shtml'
[Thu Apr 06 18:23:26.019642 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16684:tid 1188] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62514] 127.0.0.1 - - [test-dev/sid#1f4e7367798][rid#1f4e94b54f0/initial] [perdir D:/wamp64/www/test-dev/] pass through D:/wamp64/www/test-dev/ProjectTest/index.shtml

Comment: My url is still this
http://test-dev/ProjectTest/index.shtml?dynContent=apples

instead of this
http://test-dev/ProjectTest/apples

Comment: Here is my vhost directory for the test-dev site
<Directory "D:/wamp64/www/test-dev">
    Options +Includes 
 AllowOverride all
 Require all granted
 AddType text/html .shtml
    AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
 AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
 SSILegacyExprParser on
 DirectoryIndex default.shtml index.shtml default.php index.php index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dynContent=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/index.shtml http://test-dev/ProjectTest/$1/%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
</Directory>

Comment: Ok...making some progress....I got this to work....as it pulled up the apples page

http://test-dev/test

RewriteRule ^test/?$ /ProjectTest/index.shtml?dc=apples [PT]

Comment: Can you paste your vhost in your original question? It's REALLY hard to read like this :D And plz also elaborate a little on what exactly worked or if it was the full answer or just a bit of it...thx :)

Comment: Added the info to the original question

Comment: updated my answer. if that's not working, i don't now what is^^

Comment: Ok...I got this to work.....not really sure why it works....but when I type in the http://test-dev/ProjectTest/apples or http://test-dev/ProjectTest/oranges it calls up the appropriate content.
This is what I used
RewriteRule ^ProjectTest/([^/\.]+)/?$ ProjectTest/index.shtml?dynContent=$1 [L]

Comment: Huh oO ok...can you edit your original post and add that at the end? Would appreciate that :) And still don't understand why the one I gave you didn't work...anything in the rewrite log (within error.log)?

Comment: Done...posted in original under update.  Nothing really in the error logs other than what I had posted previously.  I really need to get a mod_rewrite book or something....its interesting and I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: Thanka :) Was just wondering now that you presented a working solution that does exactly the opposite of what your original question was. So pretty much turn myb answer around and you got it^^ nvm,glad you got it to finally